# Cannot edit email message body in evolution following update

Tags: email, evolution, client

I ran an update on my system and now when I open an email to send, I can add header information but not the body of the message.

How do I re-enable my message body in evolution?

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10"
```

evolution version

```
3.40.4-1ubuntu2
```

Comment: Bumping posts by editing senselessly is not permitted here on Ask Ubuntu.  Do not do it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 evolution
```

will fix the issue. (from #evolution on GIMPnet)

Bug report filed here

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=241188